# How to start an activity when system status bar is expanded/notification panel is pull down?

Tags: android, service, statusbar

I am trying to develop an application where I want to start an activity when user pull down notification panel or expand status bar on android home screen or anywhere anytime...

I tried accessibility service but couldn't succeed how to achieve it.
Is there any way to detect notification panel pull down or status bar expanded like in android system when we expand status bar the android system shows us Quick Setting Tiles for Wifi, Bluetooth etc.

Does anyone know how to access this functionality because it is already happening and I have seen it in application available on Playstore.

Tried the following but failed:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297204/how-to-detect-expanding-of-status-bar)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420320/perform-swipe-on-screen-using-accessibilityservice)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159065/detect-touch-or-swipe-on-android-phone-home-screen) and many more...